# How can I get gnuplot to use the default matlab color scheme?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to compare my data to a plot made with matlab. I want to use gnuplot, but the color scheme is different and it makes it difficult to compare the plots. How can I get gnuplot to use matlab's "jet" color theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is taken from [this page](https://gist.github.com/bagrow/805122):

```
set palette defined (0 0.0 0.0 0.5, \
1 0.0 0.0 1.0, \
2 0.0 0.5 1.0, \
3 0.0 1.0 1.0, \
4 0.5 1.0 0.5, \
5 1.0 1.0 0.0, \
6 1.0 0.5 0.0, \
7 1.0 0.0 0.0, \
8 0.5 0.0 0.0 )
```